# Date Picker plus Text in VStack does not show in Form in iOS 15

Tags: swiftui

I have a Text and DatePicker that are supposed to go in the same row, but the row simply does not appear on iOS 15. When I put an Image instead of Text it works just fine. Other objects that prevent the row from showing up are Button and Label.

I've tried this both on sim and physical device but see the same result. iOS 16+ shows the row as expected.

Here's the sample code:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                VStack {
                    Text("This text prevents the row from showing up.")
                    
                    DatePicker("", selection: .constant(Date()), displayedComponents: .date)
                        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Here's an image with the actual and expected results https://imgur.com/a/gE6nfCR

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found a solution. Adding `(spacing: 0)` to the VStack solved the issue. But the text truncated so I had to use `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on it. The final code looks like this:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("This text prevents the row from showing up.")
                       .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                    DatePicker("", selection: .constant(Date()), displayedComponents: .date)
                        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume this has something to do with the frame not being calculated correctly in older versions of SwiftUI. But I don't have any evidence. If someone could point me to a concrete reason for this bug, that would be great.